# UICollectionView Calendar - Switch to current date

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, uicollectionview

I want to add some things to Karmadust Calendar written in swift that I found online:

http://blog.karmadust.com/lets-create-a-calendar-using-a-uicollectionview/#comment-941

What I want to do is to display on the load the current section for the day the view is loaded.

And I'm struggling a bit.

I found, thanks to stackoverflow, method .scrollToItemAtIndexPath which I wanted to implement.

What the calendar is about:

1. There are couple of files. One of them is KDCalendarView: UIView.
   There are some calculations but the main I want to use is todayIndexPath: NSIndexPath - which is a location of the item for today's date.
2. I ended implementing code for todayIndexPath in ViewController once again in function.

Code below:

```
func getTodayIndexPath() -> NSIndexPath {
    let startDateCache = startDate()
    let endDateCache = endDate()
    var startOfMonthCache = NSDate()
    var todayIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
    let dayOneComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components( [NSCalendarUnit.Era, NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.Month], fromDate: startDateCache!)

    if let  gmtCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian),
        gmtTimeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") {

            gmtCalendar.timeZone = gmtTimeZone

            if let dateFromDayOneComponents = gmtCalendar.dateFromComponents(dayOneComponents) {

                startOfMonthCache = dateFromDayOneComponents

                let today = NSDate()

                if  startOfMonthCache.compare(today) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending &&
                    endDateCache!.compare(today) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {

                        let differenceFromTodayComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Day], fromDate: startOfMonthCache, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions())

                        todayIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: differenceFromTodayComponents.day, inSection: differenceFromTodayComponents.month)
                }
            }
    }
    return todayIndexPath!
}
```

In viewDidAppear I added:

```
let index: NSIndexPath = getTodayIndexPath()
        self.calendarView.calendarView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(index, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: false)
```

Everything seems fine, I got the desired view, but:

1. When you change the forItem in todayIndexPath implementation to (let's say) 14 (and we have January now) I'm getting something like this:

[image: UICollectionView problem]

The problem: I need to touch the screen to display the whole month on the screen and not the transition state from (here) December to January.

What to implement to show the whole month?

Comment: Karmadust Calendar implementation can be found be found here with all the features you desire --> [here on cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar)

Comment: I did managed to solve this problem and if I have some time I will post the answer. But thanks anyway. When I was working on this project I hadn't discovered cocoaPods yet.